# I captured my video to frames. how can i get it back as same as the original one

Tags: python

dear brothers i have a code to convert a sequence of images captured from a video file and  i want to get it back to a video file as same as the original one without losing any pixel's position in these images because i made some changes in these pixels by Encryption method (pixel value difference) in these images so how can i do that? do you have any suggestions... thank you in advance.

```
import cv2
import os
#import math
#from moviepy.editor import *

import numpy as np
import glob

img_array = []
x = 0
for filename in glob.glob('./data/*.png'):
    filename = './data/' + str(int(x)) + ".png"
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width, height)
    img_array.append(img)
    x+=1

out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 30, size)
x=0
for i in img_array:
    out.write(img_array[x])
    x+=1
out.release()
try:
    if not os.path.exists('VideoPic'):
        os.makedirs('VideoPic')
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project.mp4')
frameRate = cap.get(30)  # frame rate
x = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    frameId = cap.get(0) #current frame number
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret != True):
        break
    else:
        filename = './VideoPic/' + str(int(x)) + ".png";x+=1
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://theailearner.com/2018/10/15/creating-video-from-images-using-opencv-python/):

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
 
for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

does it don't work for you? it looks very similair to this, explain more in details what are the mismatches..

Comment: yes I take this code from the link that you mention it and it's work properly but i'm used it in a project hiding and encrypt a text in video by Aes method using Pvd so when i captured the images and make a changes in a pixels i must make it a video again re capture it again to do the work in reverse and extract the messeage that i hide it and encrypted. so I want to save the value of the pixels without any changes ....thanks for your response and i hope you can help me

Comment: I don't see the list of encrypted frames in your example but lets say the list is `encrypted_frames_list`, just replace any `img_array` with it in the snippet. It is an example for converting general list of images to video, you can bring there any list you want. Hope you'll find it useful

Comment: this is it just a test code that i take from the original code. I save the encrypted images in a folder so when i make a video from them and re captured again i don't get my message  i checked my original encrypted frames with encrypted code it's runs properly the problem happened when i convert those frames to video and re captured again and test it give wrong message in ascii position 0